# Is there any utility to manage content for eLearning site?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is there a tool available that can help manage (create courseware, upload etc) training content on AWS and provide apis to access the training content? Training material consist of audio and video files

Answer (score 0):

Try Articulate 360. They offer both online and downloadable development tools. You can create, store, share, have SMEs validate content. They even have an integrated LMS. Video development etc. I use this product for my eLearning development on a daily basis.